# Loop through Core Data using id(Int32) instead of UUID SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeItemListView: View {

//  ************************* Core Data *************************

/// `READ Meals Data` - Creates instance of from Core Data to read
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Meals.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Meals.id, ascending: true),
    ]
)  var mealData: FetchedResults<Meals>

//  ****************************************************************

var body: some View {
    List(mealData, id: \.self) { meal in
        Text(meal.meal_type ?? "Unknown")
    }

}
}
```

I know I could loop through it using UUID like:

`List(mealData, id: \.self) { meal in`

if my id were of type `UUID`, however, it is `Integer 32`. How can I loop through it? I'm interested in getting the counter.

Thank you

Comment: `id: \.self` in this case is just a pointer of NSManagedObject, so there is no reason to do not use it. And `meal.id` gives your internal id.

Comment: so how can I loop through the entity? I do not have an id UUID @Asperi or if I were to have an UUID, how can I get the current index inside the loop?

Comment: @Asperi I updated the code above, so even if I put self, I still cannot iterate through the items if id is `Integer 32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about UUID, it has nothing to this use-case, if you need to have index, just use enumerated as below

```
List(Array(mealData.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, meal in
    Text(meal.meal_type ?? "Unknown")

    // ... use index here
}
```